# Jquery Login Function doesn't work if user insert wrong credential twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "please, enter your email",
                email: "This is not a valid email!",
            },
            password: {
                required: "please, enter your password", 
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            $("#loginform").append('<div style="width:40%; margin: 20px auto;"class="loggingIn"><h4 style-"color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">Logging in ...</h4></div>'); 
            $("#loginform").append('<div class="spinningWheel" style="width:100%; text-align:center;"><img src="/images/ajaxspinner.gif" / width="50px;"></div>'); 

            $(".redFormButton").hide();

            var username = $('input[id=username]').val();  
            var password = $('input[id=password]').val(); 
            var token = $('input[id=token]').val(); 

            $.ajax({
                url: '/processLogin.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'username': username , 'password':password, 'token':token},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        $(".loggingIn").remove();
                        $(".spinningWheel").remove();
                        window.location.replace("index.php");
                    } else {
                        $(".loggingIn").remove();
                        $(".spinningWheel").remove();
                        $(".redFormButton").show();
                        $("#loginform").append('<div style="width:80%; margin: 0 auto;"class="loggingError"><h4 style="color:red; text-align:center;">the username or password is wrong. Please Check Again. </h4></div>'); 
                    }
                },
            }); // end ajax call     

            return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
        }
    });
});
```

this works perfectly either when the user use the correct credentials or when they are wrong but if the user click again login leaving the wrong username and password, the "spinning wheel" keep turning without going any further.

processLogin.php, the first time (when the data are wrong) return false but the second time it doesn't return anything:

```
<?php 

require 'core/init.php';

if ($_POST) {
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $token = filter_var($_POST['token'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if (Token::check($token)) {
        $user = new User();
        $remember = true; //this is intentional as it wasn't working
        $login = $user->login($username, $password, $remember);

        if ($login) {
            $result = true;
            echo json_encode($result);
        } else {
            $result = false;
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }
} else {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}
```

************UPDATE******************************

the problem is given from `Token::check($token)`. The second times that the script run for some reason it return false. If I remove that it always works.

```
<?php require 'core/init.php';


if($_POST){
    $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    //$token = filter_var($_POST['token'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $user = new User();
        $remember = true;
        $login = $user->login($username, $password, $remember);
        if($login) {
        echo 'true';
            } //if true login 
        else{

        echo 'false';

    }
}
```

Token Class is:

```
<?php
class Token {

    public static function generate() {
        return Session::put('token', md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

any idea how I can keep using Token?

Comment: Tip: Work on learning how to format your code for better readability. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish you are absolutely right! ;-) I know that... I will try to improve it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish btw, Any idea why this isn't working?;)

Answer (score 0):

try this trick

at this line change

```
   var username = $('input[id=username]').val();  
   var password = $('input[id=password]').val(); 
   var token = $('input[id=token]').val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: '/processLogin.php',
```

To

```
 var makhash =  (new Date).getTime();
 var username = $('input[id=username]').val();  
 var password = $('input[id=password]').val(); 
 var token = $('input[id=token]').val(); 

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/processLogin.php?hashcode='+makhash,
```

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem.  it still return 'false' the first time (as expected since I put the wrong password) and it goes straight to the end of processLogin.php the second time without evaluating any of the code written above. the last line.

Comment: try to reset the form using jquery if user has failed login

Comment: I tried that using `$('#loginform')[0].reset();` , the problem is still there. I can't figure it out why. `False` first time and then it returns whatever I echo out at the of processLogin.php

Comment: i am sorry for that really but i think you need to re-write your code using static `variable` true or false if forum has errors

Comment: the problem is given from Token class not from jquery. I updated my question. Any idea why is not working. May be because is a static method?

Comment: yes maybe try to remove the static ` public static function generate() ` and from `public static function check($token)`